# How can I add external jars to SparkContext in local mode for use in a Spring service?

Tags: jar

I want add externals jars in sparkContext and needs to available to use.

I have tried

```
sparkConf.setAppName("SchemaReader")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.authenticate", "false")
                .set("spark.driver.memory", "4096M")
                .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "PATH")
                .set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "PATH");
```

this properties are work when we submit through spark-submit and Spark launcher, But here i am trying to up spark session in spring service in local mode there it is showing message added jar in sparkContext, but it is not available to use.